# Chunking bytes (not strings) in Python 2 and 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

This is turning out to be trickier than I expected.  I have a byte string:

```
data = b'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

I want to read this data in chunks of *n* bytes.  Under Python 2, this is trivial using a minor modification to the `grouper` recipe from the `itertools` documentation:

```
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return (''.join(x) for x in izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args))
```

With this in place, I can call:

```
>>> list(grouper(data, 2))
```

And get:

```
['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh', 'ij', 'kl', 'mn', 'op', 'qr', 'st', 'uv', 'wx', 'yz']
```

Under Python 3, this gets trickier.  The `grouper` function as written
simply falls over:

```
>>> list(grouper(data, 2))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <genexpr>
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found
```

And this is because in Python 3, when you iterate over a bytestring (like `b'foo'`), you get a list of integers, rather than a list of bytes:

```
>>> list(b'foo')
[102, 111, 111]
```

The python 3 `bytes` function will help out here:

```
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return (bytes(x) for x in izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args))
```

Using that, I get what I want:

```
>>> list(grouper(data, 2))
[b'ab', b'cd', b'ef', b'gh', b'ij', b'kl', b'mn', b'op', b'qr', b'st', b'uv', b'wx', b'yz']
```

But (of course!) the `bytes` function under Python 2 does not behave
the same way.  It's just an alias for `str`, so that results in:

```
>>> list(grouper(data, 2))
["('a', 'b')", "('c', 'd')", "('e', 'f')", "('g', 'h')", "('i', 'j')", "('k', 'l')", "('m', 'n')", "('o', 'p')", "('q', 'r')", "('s', 't')", "('u', 'v')", "('w', 'x')", "('y', 'z')"]
```

...which is not at all helpful.  I ended up writing the following:

```
def to_bytes(s):
    if six.PY3:
        return bytes(s)
    else:
        return ''.encode('utf-8').join(list(s))

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return (to_bytes(x) for x in izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args))
```

This seems to work, but is this really the way to do it?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, thanks for that pointer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Funcy](http://funcy.readthedocs.org/en/stable/overview.html) (a library offering various useful utilities, supporting both Python 2 and 3) offers a [`chunks` function](http://funcy.readthedocs.org/en/stable/seqs.html#chunks) that does exactly this:

```
>>> import funcy
>>> data = b'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> list(funcy.chunks(6, data))
[b'abcdef', b'ghijkl', b'mnopqr', b'stuvwx', b'yz']   # Python 3
['abcdef', 'ghijkl', 'mnopqr', 'stuvwx', 'yz']        # Python 2.7
```

Alternatively, you could include a simple implementation of this in your program (compatible with both Python 2.7 and 3):

```
def chunked(size, source):
    for i in range(0, len(source), size):
        yield source[i:i+size]
```

It behaves the same (at least for your data; Funcy's `chunks` also works with iterators, this doesn't):

```
>>> list(chunked(6, data))
[b'abcdef', b'ghijkl', b'mnopqr', b'stuvwx', b'yz']   # Python 3
['abcdef', 'ghijkl', 'mnopqr', 'stuvwx', 'yz']        # Python 2.7
```

Comment: Ok, but source can't be iterable in your function `chunked`

Comment: @vlk I know, I explicitly mention this in my answer. But the question wasn't about iterators, but about bytestrings. If you need to use iterators, consider the funcy solution.

Answer (score 3):

Using `bytes` with `bytearray` would work for both if your string length was divisible by n or you pass a non empty string as the fillvalue:

```
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return ((bytes(bytearray(x))) for x in zip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args))
```

py3:

```
In [20]: import sys

In [21]: sys.version
Out[21]: '3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29) \n[GCC 4.8.4]'

In [22]: print(list(grouper(data,2)))
[b'ab', b'cd', b'ef', b'gh', b'ij', b'kl', b'mn', b'op', b'qr', b'st', b'uv', b'wx', b'yz']
```

Py2:

```
In [6]: import sys

In [7]: sys.version
Out[7]: '2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) \n[GCC 4.8.2]'

In [8]: print(list(grouper(data,2)))
['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh', 'ij', 'kl', 'mn', 'op', 'qr', 'st', 'uv', 'wx', 'yz']
```

If you passed an empty string you could filter them out:

```
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return ((bytes(bytearray(filter(None, x)))) for x in zip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args))
```

Which will work for any length string.

```
In [29]: print(list(grouper(data,4)))
[b'abcd', b'efgh', b'ijkl', b'mnop', b'qrst', b'uvwx', b'yz']

In [30]: print(list(grouper(data,3)))
[b'abc', b'def', b'ghi', b'jkl', b'mno', b'pqr', b'stu', b'vwx', b'yz']
```