# Convert Cluster object into byte or bytearray object

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, scikit-learn, byte

## Goal

I would like to insert a cluster object from scikit-learn into a sql-server table (varbinary(max) column).

I'm creating a Big Data development and test environment for our analytics team.  I know there are better options but sql-server and python are what I have to work with at the moment.

## Problem

I need to be able to convert a cluster object, in this example MiniBatchKMeans object, to a byte or byte array to be able to insert into a sql-server table.  I get a type error that the MiniBatchKMeans object is not iterable.

What I the best approach to attack this problem?  Do I need to find the beginning address of the MiniBatchKMeans object, then the size of the object and iterate over the block of memory one byte at a time?

I found a reference: [on how to chunk a byte string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35580801/chunking-bytes-not-strings-in-python-2-and-3) but that doesn't seem to help.

#### Test Code for Conversion

```
def Test_03():
    # variables
    string_byte_error_msg = 'No error'
    string_bytearray_error_msg = 'No error'
    bool_byte_no_error = False
    bool_bytearray_no_error = False

    # generate knn cluster object
    clust_knn_obj = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters = 10, init = 'k-means++', n_init = 5)

    # convert to byte type
    try:
        byte_knn_clust = bytes(clust_knn_obj)
    except TypeError as e_t:
        string_byte_error_msg = e_t.args[0]
    except Exception as e:
        string_byte_error_msg = e.args[0]
    else:
        bool_byte_no_error = True
    finally:
        pass

    # convert to byte array
    try:
        byte_array_knn_clust = bytearray(clust_knn_obj)
    except TypeError as ba_e_t:
        string_bytearray_error_msg = ba_e_t.args[0]
    except Exception as ba_e:
        string_bytearray_error_msg = ba_e.args[0]
    else:
        bool_bytearray_no_error = True
    finally:
        pass

    # below will insert into the mssql database in a varbinary(max) column
    #...
    pass
```

#### Error Messages

```
string_byte_error_msg = "'MiniBatchKMeans' object is not iterable"
string_bytearray_error_msg = "'MiniBatchKMeans' object is not iterable"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved this problem.  As a beginner I now of the existence of "pickle."  So I pickled the object and saved it on a drive to be pulled for future use.